# Why does Flow reject tuples made of intersections of unions?

Tags: javascript, flowtype

In the following code, I don't understand why Flow rejects my `kv` tuple.

```js
// @flow

type String = {
  type: "string",
  value: string
};

type Number = {
  type: "number",
  value: number
};

type Value = Number | String;

type Foo = { foo: "bar" } & Value;

let obj: Foo = {
  foo: "bar",
  type: "number",
  value: 42
};

let kv: [string, Foo] = ["obj", obj];
```

Flow seems to successfully type-check `obj` as a `Foo`, but doesn't want me to use it in a `[string, Foo]` tuple.

Indeed I get the following error:

```
23: let kv: [string, Foo] = ["obj", obj];
                                    ^ intersection type. This type is incompatible with
15: type Foo = { foo: "bar" } & Value;
                                ^ union: Number | String
```

What is going on?

Comment: I think this is a bug, please open an issue on https://github.com/facebook/flow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unfortunate that "Try Flow" doesn't provide you with a full trace of type errors. If you go [here](https://flowtype.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQiAuBPADgU1AZRQE4CWAdgOagC8oA3oqKOtgFygBEAzoaWWwDT1QANwCG0AK5ZWXYuUQBfANzImOAHLiAtgCMsBKrUGrWbElt0F+g0RKmgzOvQuWpMOAGpjJBjY-0AfPG5yF1VQADFYWAMaUEgok20RS1B5UAAyUE9bF2gsFFBYbQArVkjo6joGeNhE5KsGY3YHCwbhLzsAFgAmZ2Q8goBrIVYAbRkePgiogF0DUbYi4v5CkpnFIA) and click "json" you can dig through and find out more about what's happening.

#### The Problem: Non-Determinism

The way to think of this is as an inheritance problem. Flow is trying to determine with certainty what type Foo is. Because there is nothing to indicate in Foo's declaration whether it is { foo } & Number or { foo } & String, Flow seems to naively try to apply both.

So in line 23, flow is saying, "the type isn't Foo because I would expect the property "type" to be "string" and "value" to be type "number". But if you switched it, Flow would still error.

Here's another way I think of the problem:

```
class String
class Number
class Value extends String || Number  // <= unable to determine what Foo is extending
type Foo = { stuff } & Value // <== ...locked-in non-deterministic
```

In this case, Flow is unable to determine what "Foo" is extending, but has some logic to resolve the type if some variable is assigned a Value type. But...

When the Foo alias is created, Value is still non-deterministic, and it's like Flow tries to lock down Foo. Flow will throw an error as soon as you access a property.

Fortunately there are two simple approaches to solving the problem.

#### Disjoint Unions

The first involves a feature called [disjoint unions](https://flowtype.org/blog/2015/07/03/Disjoint-Unions.html). [Here's a working example](https://flowtype.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQiAuBPADgU1AMVrKALygDeokBAXKAEQBGAhgE62gC+y62oAyiswCWAOwDmxPAVAAyMolChuWGrQDOAkaNoAaeaABujaAFdlodULGJ2Abi6YcAOWMBbelmYT8hWaT1KVYVd3Vl0FQxMzILcPaztUB1AANSNTCWcYzwAfPg0xeOgsFFBYegArGm8JPwVKWBUmUP8HQOCPHT0I0xoAFgAmOORC4oBrfRoAbQtNbUlYAF0JCdpSsp0S8vmbIA).

```
type Foo = { foo: "bar" }

type String = Foo & {
  type: "string",
  value: string
};

type Number = Foo & {
  type: "number",
  value: number
};

type Value = Number | String;

let obj: Foo = {
  foo: "bar",
  type: "number",
  value: 42
};

let kv: [string, Foo] = ["obj", obj]; // no errors!
```

Why does this work? Again, imagine you wrote this with an inheritance pattern:

```
class Foo;
class String extends Foo; // <== deterministic
class Number extends Foo; // <== deterministic
var Value = String | Number // <== enum of certain classes, so still deterministic
```

#### Object-Type Spreads (unreleased)

If you grab the latest master branch of Flow, there's also a cool feature coming, object-type spreads. [Here's an example](https://flowtype.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQiAuBPADgU1AZRQE4CWAdgOagC8oA3oqKOtgFygBEAzoaWWwDT1QANwCG0AK5ZWXYuUQBfANzImOAHLiAtgCMsBKrUGrWbElt0F+g0RKmgzOvQuWpMOAGpjJBjY-0AfPG5yF1VQADFYWAMaUEgok20RSz5QADoMz1tQeWRoLBRQWG0AK1ZI6Oo6BnjYROSrBmN2BwtG4S87ABYAJmc8gqKUAAs9AHlS8qiYwVr6lKM3VgByGR5lgQYbSRWASVARTQPQNfINhQHCgGshVgBtU7JUioBdAzu2YpL+ItKXxSAA):

```
// @flow (master branch)

type String = {
  type: "string",
  value: string
};

type Number = {
  type: "number",
  value: number
};

type Value = Number | String;

type Foo = { foo: "bar", ...Value }

let obj: Foo = {
  foo: "bar",
  type: "number",
  value: 42
}; // no error!

let otherObj: Foo = {
  foo: "bar",
  type: 'string',
  value: 'I am a string',
}; // no error!
```

Comment: Thanks. I had already taken the first approach to fix my issue. Object-type spreads is indeed very handy as it remove the need to write `Foo` everywhere. Can't wait for it to be released. :)